# I have received rep points that I don't deserve

Tags: discussion, reputation

On the following question:[wxpython frame doesn't re-draw it's contents in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974467/wxpython-frame-doesnt-re-draw-its-contents-in-while-loop/33981543#33981543)

I added a bit of presentation to an existing answer and specifically said that my answer was not to be accepted. It was, how can I ensure that the person who posted the original answer gets their answer accepted, short of asking the OP to change their vote. No one wants to come across as a leech.

Comment: You can't. It doesn't really matter that much, the accept mark is super arbitrary often enough.

Comment: You didn't rip him off, you provided (some) attribution and then expanded his answer.  Would be nice if you actually linked to his answer as part of the attribution though.

Comment: Problem solved, the OP changed their vote when asked to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that is not big problem.

Because when user ask an answer **OP needs answer which fulfill OP needs**. If **your answer same** or if **your answer different**  from other **it doesn't matter**. All you OP need is only Correct answer.

OP has accepted your answer for that reason.

> > > In your question ***I added a bit of presentation to an existing answer***, thats lead you to accepting yours rather than other

1. [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
2. [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

> If you have to edit **just few thing you can Edit the question** as well. If **you have new idea or new answer which various from other answer You are free to add it**

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely up the person asking the question who they decide to award the check mark to. You can point out why another answer is better, but ultimately you have no say in the matter. The only thing you can do to prevent your answer from being accepted is to delete it, and I wouldn't recommend that in this case. No one is going to think you're a "leech" if you properly attributed your source.